# bsd-finger won't Make correctly

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I ran across an interesting issue. My system is Arch Linux (latest) on an ASUS laptop. Now, the really weird issue:

finger is not automatically installed with Arch. I attempted to use pacman to install it, and it's not in the repositories. It IS in the AUR.

I downloaded the AUR file, un-tarred the tar with `tar -xvf bsd-finger0.17.tar.gz`. This created the directory folder with the same name. I ran `./configure` which gave the expected output:

```
` /usr/man
Looking for a C compiler... gcc
Checking if gcc accepts gcc warnings... yes
Checking if gcc accepts -O2... yes
Checking for socklen_t... yes
Checking for snprintf declaration... ok
Checking for snprintf implementation... ok
Generating MCONFIG...`
```

Then I tried to make, and got this weird tidbit: http://pastebin.com/0qACttCu

So, it looks like it's having weird compiling issues. Any ideas on what's up here?

Comment: Have you tried what is written in the error message? (include time.h?)

Comment: @arved that worked for the first error, but now I have this: http://pastebin.com/KmErbVad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what AUR is, but it seems you are not using it the way it is supposed to be used.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Build_and_install_the_package

That wiki says that you should build an AUR package with "makepkg"

But anyway looking at
https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=netkit-bsd-finger

It seems you just need to add time.h as include to two files and it should compile.

Comment: The file does not HAVE a PKGBUILD file. That's the big problem. and why I am forced to compile it.

Comment: Thanks though. I didn't realize it was both files. It worked now. I appreciate the help, as I'm not versed in C whatsoever.